# How to authorize gmail to read my inbox using botframework web channel

Tags: c#, google-oauth, botframework, gmail-api

I'm trying to use service of gmail to read inbox data and to show them in my chatbot. I want to authenticate using my account of gmail. When i test the chatbot in bot emulator works fine, the problem start when i deploy on web..i cannot authenticate on web.

```
string jsonPath2 = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "client_secret_webapp.json";


        UserCredential credential;

        string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly };
        string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
           System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);



        using (var stream = new FileStream(jsonPath2, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for read-only access to the authenticated 
                // user's account, but not other types of account access.
                new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly,},
                "xxxx@gmail.com",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
            );
        }
        var gmailService = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
        });

        log.Info("ApplicationName" + ApplicationName);

        var emailListRequest = gmailService.Users.Messages.List("xxxxx@gmail.com");
        emailListRequest.LabelIds = "INBOX";
        emailListRequest.MaxResults = 1;
        emailListRequest.Q = "is:unread";
        emailListRequest.IncludeSpamTrash = false;




        if (emailListResponse != null && emailListResponse.Messages != null)
        {
            //loop through each email and get what fields you want... 
            foreach (var email in emailListResponse.Messages)
            {

                var emailInfoRequest = gmailService.Users.Messages.Get("xxxxxx@gmail.com", email.Id);

                var emailInfoResponse = emailInfoRequest.Execute();



                if (emailInfoResponse != null)
                {
                    String from = "";
                    String date = "";
                    String subject = "";
                    String body = "";
                    //loop through the headers to get from,date,subject, body  
                    foreach (var mParts in emailInfoResponse.Payload.Headers)
                    {


                        if (mParts.Name == "Date")
                        {
                            date = mParts.Value;
                        }
                        else if (mParts.Name == "From")
                        {
                            from = mParts.Value;
                        }
                        else if (mParts.Name == "Subject")
                        {
                            subject = mParts.Value;
                        }

                        if (date != "" && from != "")
                        {




                            if (emailInfoResponse.Payload.Parts == null && emailInfoResponse.Payload.Body != null)
                                body = DecodeBase64String(emailInfoResponse.Payload.Body.Data);
                            else
                                body = GetNestedBodyParts(emailInfoResponse.Payload.Parts, "");




                        }

                    }
                    await context.PostAsync("Email list for: Date " + date + " :::::::::::  From:  " + from + " ::::::::::::  Subject  " + subject + " : :::::::::::::  Body :  " + body + " Email.id eshte " + email.Id);

                }

            }

        }

    }


    static String DecodeBase64String(string s)
    {
        var ts = s.Replace("-", "+");
        ts = ts.Replace("_", "/");
        var bc = Convert.FromBase64String(ts);
        var tts = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bc);

        return tts;
    }


    static String GetNestedBodyParts(IList<MessagePart> part, string curr)
    {
        string str = curr;
        if (part == null)
        {
            return str;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var parts in part)
            {
                if (parts.Parts == null)
                {
                    if (parts.Body != null && parts.Body.Data != null)
                    {
                        var ts = DecodeBase64String(parts.Body.Data);
                        str += ts;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return GetNestedBodyParts(parts.Parts, str);
                }
            }

            return str;
        }
    }







    private static byte[] FromBase64ForUrlString(string base64ForUrlInput)
    {
        int padChars = (base64ForUrlInput.Length % 4) == 0 ? 0 : (4 - (base64ForUrlInput.Length % 4));
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(base64ForUrlInput, base64ForUrlInput.Length + padChars);
        result.Append(String.Empty.PadRight(padChars, '='));
        result.Replace('-', '+');
        result.Replace('_', '/');
        return Convert.FromBase64String(result.ToString());
    }
```

client_id.json

```
   {"installed":{"client_id":"xxxxxxx- yyyyyy.apps.googleusercontent.com","project_id":"reademailbot","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"yyyyyyyyyyy","redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"]}}
```

Edited:

I try to add the code below :

```
   var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new 
            ClientSecrets
            {
            ClientId = "xx- 
            xxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-lLO"
             },
                                                            new[] { 
            GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly,

            GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom, 
            GmailService.Scope.GmailMetadata 
            },
                                                            "user",

         CancellationToken.None,
                                                            new 
        FileDataStore("Drive.Auth.Store")).Result;

        var gmailService = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.GmailService(new 
        BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        });
```

But when i try on web i have still problem :

> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
>
> The redirect URI in the request, http://127.0.0.1:52158/authorize/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/673194113721-45u2pgl6m2l74ecf13c51fmmihrsu3jh.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=673194113721

Edit 2 :

```
  string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly };
        string ApplicationName = "IkanbiBot";


        var secrets = new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["GMailClientId"],
            ClientSecret = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["GMailClientSecret"]
        };

        var token = new Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse { RefreshToken = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["GmailRefreshToken"] };
        var credential = new UserCredential(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
            {
                ClientSecrets = secrets
            }), "xxxx@gmail.com", token);

        var gmailService = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
        });

        log4net.ILog log2 = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        await context.PostAsync("Aplication name is ..." + ApplicationName);

        await context.PostAsync("secret name is ..." + secrets.ClientId + "_____   and  .... " + secrets.ClientSecret + " ++++ token is " + token.RefreshToken);

        var emailListRequest = gmailService.Users.Messages.List("xxxxx@gmail.com");
        emailListRequest.LabelIds = "INBOX";
        emailListRequest.MaxResults = 1;
        emailListRequest.Q = "is:unread";
        emailListRequest.IncludeSpamTrash = false;

        // Get our emails
        // Get our emails
        var emailListResponse = emailListRequest.Execute();

        //get our emails 

        log2.Info(emailListResponse.Messages);

       await context.PostAsync("emailListResponse  is ..." + emailListResponse.Messages.Count);
        if (emailListResponse != null && emailListResponse.Messages != null)
        {
            //loop through each email and get what fields you want... 
            foreach (var email in emailListResponse.Messages)
            {

                var emailInfoRequest = gmailService.Users.Messages.Get("botikanbi@gmail.com", email.Id);

                var emailInfoResponse = emailInfoRequest.Execute();



                if (emailInfoResponse != null)
                {
                    String from = "";
                    String date = "";
                    String subject = "";
                    String body = "";
                    //loop through the headers to get from,date,subject, body  
                    foreach (var mParts in emailInfoResponse.Payload.Headers)
                    {


                        if (mParts.Name == "Date")
                        {
                            date = mParts.Value;
                        }
                        else if (mParts.Name == "From")
                        {
                            from = mParts.Value;
                        }
                        else if (mParts.Name == "Subject")
                        {
                            subject = mParts.Value;
                        }

                        if (date != "" && from != "")
                        {




                            if (emailInfoResponse.Payload.Parts == null && emailInfoResponse.Payload.Body != null)
                                body = DecodeBase64String(emailInfoResponse.Payload.Body.Data);
                            else
                                body = GetNestedBodyParts(emailInfoResponse.Payload.Parts, "");




                        }

                    }
                    await context.PostAsync("Email list for: Date " + date + " :::::::::::  From:  " + from + " ::::::::::::  Subject  " + subject + " : :::::::::::::  Body :  " + body + " Email.id eshte " + email.Id);

                }

            }

        }

    }


    static String DecodeBase64String(string s)
    {
        var ts = s.Replace("-", "+");
        ts = ts.Replace("_", "/");
        var bc = Convert.FromBase64String(ts);
        var tts = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bc);

        return tts;
    }


    static String GetNestedBodyParts(IList<MessagePart> part, string curr)
    {
        string str = curr;
        if (part == null)
        {
            return str;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var parts in part)
            {
                if (parts.Parts == null)
                {
                    if (parts.Body != null && parts.Body.Data != null)
                    {
                        var ts = DecodeBase64String(parts.Body.Data);
                        str += ts;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return GetNestedBodyParts(parts.Parts, str);
                }
            }

            return str;
        }
    }







    private static byte[] FromBase64ForUrlString(string base64ForUrlInput)
    {
        int padChars = (base64ForUrlInput.Length % 4) == 0 ? 0 : (4 - (base64ForUrlInput.Length % 4));
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(base64ForUrlInput, base64ForUrlInput.Length + padChars);
        result.Append(String.Empty.PadRight(padChars, '='));
        result.Replace('-', '+');
        result.Replace('_', '/');
        return Convert.FromBase64String(result.ToString());
    }


}
```

}

Now i'm using this code . I get answer from the bot till : 
           "secret name is ..." + secrets.ClientId + "_____   and  .... " + secrets.ClientSecret + " ++++ token is " + token.RefreshToken 
But stop when try to read email :(

Can you help me please what is going on ?

Comment: Did you check the web chat channel error logs? You can also get some details if you use App Insights on Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are sevral ways to authcate to google.

- moble
- web
- sevice account
- native applications.

The client you create for each of the above authentication types is different.  The code to use them is also different.

`GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync` is used to authenticate installed applications.  Its wont work with a web application.

For a web application you should be following [Web applications (ASP.NET MVC)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc) and using `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow`

```
  private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
            {
                ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = "PUT_CLIENT_ID_HERE",
                    ClientSecret = "PUT_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE"
                },
                Scopes = new[] {  GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly },
                DataStore = new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString()
            });
```

**redirect_uri_mismatch**

In order to use the api your client must be set up corectly.  In google developer console you simply need to add the proper redirect uri in the settings on your client and it will work.  It must match exactly `http://127.0.0.1:52158/authorize/`  make sure that visual studio isnt creating random port numbers on you.

Comment: Should i have G Suite to read my gmail inbox using a web application ? I trying in different mode without result :(

Comment: You only need Gsuite if you are trying to use a service account.  Other wise you can use gmail api to read any google account using Oauth2.    Check my edit on your redirect uri error

Comment: What will the redirect when i'm using web channel for my chatbot , the link is below : https://xxxxxx/ReadEmail/default.htm

Comment: I still have problem when i put GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow instead of  GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker ...i cannot get data from my gmail account in my bot using Botframework, web channel

Comment: I edit my question again ,still i cannot retrieve message from gmail

Comment: Define stop what is the error you are seeing?  what is in emailListResponse ?

Comment: Go into %appdata% see if you can find where its storing your credentials you need to reauthenticate your user.  The credentials are expired.  Look for something like Auth.store delete the files in that folder

Comment: When i run the chatbot in emulator using localhost works fine ( code 1 in my question), when i use code (edit 2 in question) in web , send error : Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: Error:"unauthorized_client" . I cannot retrieve gmail login page to authorize the gmail...how to resolve this please ?